# .htaccess mod_rewrite on multiple PHP files issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to beautify URL's for SEO from http://example.net/dashboard.php?action=news to http://example.net/news
And it's working with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/+dashboard\.php\?([^\&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ dashboard.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I want to edit more PHP files, for example, http://example.net/user.php?action=profile to http://example.net/profile

If I use this code again in the same .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/+user\.php\?([^\&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ user.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It won't work, only dashboard.php one is working properly.
Can you please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the .htaccess looks like now? And what is happening after visiting profile page?

Comment: Do you only have `news` and `profile`? Or are there other URLs that you rewrite as well? Your first rule matches `/<anything>` and rewrites to `dashboard.php?action=<anything>` - so there is naturally going to be a conflict if you introduce another rule with the same regex. This seems far too general for how you describe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your current Rewriterules are to general.

```
[^/]+
```

matches everything which has no "/", else its matching everything.
So basicly your first rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ dashboard.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

matches everytime. profile/ will always redirected to dashboard.php?acton=profile.

Your .htaccess should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/+dashboard\.php\?([^\&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(news)/?$ dashboard.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/+user\.php\?([^\&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(profile)/?$ user.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you can see i switched

```
[^/]+
```

with more explicit regex.

Comment: This is working, but the problem is that my website is full of subpages with user.php?action=something, is there an easier way to do it, or I must enter every page name in your .htaccess example?

Comment: As far as i can see its not possible now. You would have to switch the called URL to something like http://example.net/user/profile and http://example.net/dashboard/news. In this case you RewriteRule would be `RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/? $1.php?action=$2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. We'll go with another solution then.